# Reading scientific papers (pdf) on Kindle paperwhite

Tags: pdf, kindle

I'm considering asking Santa a Kindle Paperwhite.

My primary use would be to read scientific papers, mostly about physics, and with equations. These papers would be in PDF format, and often two columns.

What can I expect then ? Is there a need to convert/reformat the PDF firsts ? How does the kindle paperwhite display equations, and/or non roman alphabets ?

Comment: If you vote to close, please let me know where I should ask then.

Comment: You could try SuperUser, or possibly [googling it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=kindle+scientific+papers&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGB566GB566&oq=kindle+scienti&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3331j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), given that the [first link back](http://www.abstractmodem.com/2012/11/reading_academic_papers_on_a_kindle_paperwhite/) is a detailed examination of this question.

Comment: Hum, thanks for the link, I feel a bit stupid now !

Answer (score 19):

[k2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) is the most effective thing I've found, by far.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks a lot for sharing it :-)

Comment: Does this work well on research paper that has math formulas in it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, k2pdfopt is the best choice. To make it easier to use, I made this service for anyone want to read academic papers on kindle like me.
Link:  http://wooya.me/post/kindle-pdf-optimization-service/

Comment: It'd be great if you make it open source.